# How to pull image from existing azure container registry?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service, azure-container-registry

Created a docker image. Deployed the app as web service; create a registry and push the image to azure container and the app is running fine online. I tried to login but cant. Username or password incorrect. On top of that my laptop crashed and I did not save a copy.

Can someone help me on how to pull the image from acr with the source code and download to my local machine. I found some tutorial online but was a bit vague.

Please help

Comment: What *have* you tried? What hasn't worked? There's tons of documentation on how to authenticate and pull images from ACR. Until you provide some context about any specific issues you're encountering, the best recommendation anyone can give is "look at the documentation"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Login to your Azure account

```bash
az login
```

2. Login to Azure Container Registry

```bash
az acr login --name $REGISTRY
```

3. Pull your Image

```bash
docker pull ${REGISTRY}.azurecr.io/${IMAGE}:${TAG}
```

Optionnal:
List your images

```
az acr repository list -n $REGISTRY --output table
```